# How to display the algorithm2e at the center of the frame in the beamer?

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

I want to display my algorithm in the center of the frame like the sentence `hello world` in the code. Here is my code and the output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    hello world!
  \end{center}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[m+1]$\;
    \LinesNumbered
    \ForEach{row $i$}{
      \For{$l=ptr[i]$ \KwTo $prt[i+1]-1$}{
     $ y[i] \leftarrow y[i]+val[l] \cdot x[ind[l]]$ \;
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to move `\end{center}` after `\end{algorithm}`?

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not so pretty solution**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    hello world!

%\fbox{% fbox helps to find the minimal width for the minipage below
  \begin{minipage}{.55\linewidth} % find the minimal value to enclose the code
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[m+1]$\;
    \LinesNumbered
    \ForEach{row $i$}{
      \For{$l=ptr[i]$ \KwTo $prt[i+1]-1$}{
     $ y[i] \leftarrow y[i]+val[l] \cdot x[ind[l]]$ \;
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
%  }% end of fbox
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I have to manually adjust the width of the minipage to look right, it is OK for me.